# Update Parent and Child Record at once throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently trying to update a Parent Record and also a Child Record at the same time in Spring.

My Parent Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "UserSequence")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UserSequence",
            strategy = "com.simagdo.test.utils.SequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "100"),
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;
    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH
            }
    )
    private Address userAddress;
```

The Address Entity looks like this (Not all Columns are included):

```
@Entity(name = "Address")
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "AddressSequence")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "AddressSequence",
            strategy = "com.simagdo.test.utils.SequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "120"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;
    @Column(
            name = "City",
            length = 40
    )
    private String city;
    @Column(
            name = "Country",
            length = 80
    )
```

I want to update the User Entity and also the Address of the User at the same time. For that, I'm using the following code:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/updateUser/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> updateRecord(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody User updateUser) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found: " + id));

    user.setAnnualRevenue(updateUser.getAnnualRevenue());
    user.setBillingAddress(updateUser.getBillingAddress());
    user.setDescription(updateUser.getDescription());
    user.setEmployees(updateUser.getEmployees());
    user.setDeleted(updateUser.isDeleted());
    user.setName(updateUser.getName());
    user.setPhone(updateUser.getPhone());
    user.setShippingAddress(updateUser.getShippingAddress());
    user.setType(updateUser.getType());
    user.setWebsite(updateUser.getWebsite());

    this.userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
}
```

But when I send a PUT Request, I get the following Error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace? Also all fields for both entities should be included, as a StackOverflowError usually indicates a circular reference or a method which is calling itself over and over

Comment: Do you have equals, hashcode or toString implemented in those Entities?

Comment: This is the full Stacktrace i get. Also, i don't have any equals, hashcode or toString methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely returning a User object that is referencing an Address and this same address is also referencing the user class. That's why you are getting a stack overflow error. I can't assure this because you didn't expose the whole classes. If you did this, checkout the solution.

This is a common error, don't worry about.

SOLUTION:
1- On the users class, add the JsonManagedReference annotation on the Address field.

2- In the addresses class, add the JsonBackReference annotation on the User field.

Now, when your application convert your User instance to Json, it will add the field annotated with JsonManagedReference and will ignore the field JsonBackReference and stack overflow will not be thrown.

Comment: The Problem is that only my User class has a Reference to the Address. On the Address Entity there is no Link to the User becuase i want to use the Address Entity for different Entities. But i tried your Solution and i still get the same Error.

Comment: Have you debugged to know exactly which part of the code is throwing stackoverflow? If this is happening after the API return the value, probably this is the issue but maybe it's happening on different fields.

Comment: The Problem occurs when i want to update the Billing Address. When i debug it, it fails at this line:  this.accountRepository.saveAndFlush(account);